# asynchronous JavaScript static function variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a problem with a "static" function in javascrip (nodejs server).

```
User.create = function(data, _callback){        
    var node = db.createNode(data);
    var _user = new User(node);
    _user.save(function(err){
        if(err) return callback(err, null);
        _user.index(function(err){
            if(err) return callback(err, null);
            callback(null, _user);  
        })
    })
};
```

If I call this function twice the _user variable in the internal callback function takes the new value, it seems it overrides the function var instead of allocate a new one.

I need calling this function to allocate a new variable, so it waits save and index functions to complete without changing _user variable.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript variables are indeed function scoped, so there wouldn't be any explanation for `var _user` not defining a new variable on subsequent runs.

Looking at the code, I would be more suspicious of what's happening in your User constructor - perhaps it contains some scoping or other logical issues resulting in identical users being created on subsequent calls. Similar "suspects" would be the `data` parameter getting passed in, as well as `db.createNode()`. Only suggesting these areas, because it's more likely that there's a programmatic issue at play, rather than JavaScript not following the rules :)

Also, I noticed that your `User.create` function accepts a parameter called `_callback`, but later on is invoking `callback`. I don't know if that's a typo in your example, or if you're accidentally invoking a callback from a higher scope not shown in the example, but that could produce weird behavior.